# Facing issue in date while getting record from salesforce:mule

Tags: csv, salesforce, mule, mule-studio, mule-component

I am facing issue while reading data from SalesForce.
Current Scenario:
Read data from SalesForce account and store into csv file.
In SalesForce whenever we insert data at that time createdDate field store as current date. My problem is when I read data from SalesForce at that time in csv file it store current date as (createdDate+1) in few of records not in all records.

For example my date is 1/12/2015 in csv file it store 13th. 
Didn't get any idea why this is happened.

My flow is

```
http->salesforce->data_mapper->file-outbound
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 1):

This is more than probably a TimeZone issue, let's say that salesforce server is in UTC and that your computer is in GMT+4 because you are in Rusia. Any record from 22:00 or later will show up as +1 days.

Set the default timezone of Java, your system or otherwise manipulate the dates with [MEL datetime functions](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Mule+Expression+Language+Date+and+Time+Functions).